# Rule of Traffic light

Tags: basel

I heard that there is a rule called Traffic light from Basel which is used to backtesting the VaR numbers.

However I could not find exactly which regulation from Basel mandates that, although I am overall familiar of this rule.

Could you please help me with any reference to exactly which rule first introduced the Traffic light for VaR backtesting.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0970389612000778) reference:

> The back testing approach of the Basel Committee (Basel Committee for
> banking Basel Committee on Banking Supervision, 1996), often called
> the “traffic light” approach, divides the number of exceptions that a
> model reports into green, yellow and red zones based on a trade-off
> between type I and type II error assuming that the probability of
> observing an exception is binomially distributed. A model in the green
> zone is acceptable to supervisors while a model in the other two zones
> results in penalties imposed upon the bank. The first performance
> measure used in this paper is the regulatory back test prescribed by
> the Basel Committee (Basel Committee for banking Basel Committee on
> Banking Supervision, 1996).
>
> The penalty structure for the regulatory back test is as follows:
> $$P_t = \begin{cases}
> >     0 & \text{if } N \leq 4 \text{ green zone} \\
> >     0.4 \text{ to } 0.85 & \text{if } 5 \leq N \leq 9 \text{ yellow zone} \\
> >     1 & \text{if } N > 10 \text{ red zone} \end{cases}$$
>
> where N refers to the number of 99% VaR exceptions over a 250 trading
> day time frame.

Comment: This document may aslo be of interest to you https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs22.pdf *Supervisory framework for the use of 'backtesting' in conjunction with the internal models approach to market risk capital requirements* 04-jan-1996